# How can I set border to Image control in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, image, uwp, windows-phone

How can I apply a rounded border to Image control in UWP xaml page so that this Image will also have rounded corners?
I tried

```xml
<Border BorderBrush="White"
        BorderThickness="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Height="183"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="316"
        Canvas.ZIndex="1">
    <Image x:Name="carImage"
           Height="183"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Width="306"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           IsTapEnabled="False"
           IsRightTapEnabled="False"
           IsHoldingEnabled="False"
           IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"
           Stretch="UniformToFill"
           Margin="-1,-1,9,-1"/>
</Border>
```

But without success.
Is there any way to do this or am I so blind I can't see an obvious solution?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You haven't set the `CornerRadius` on the border. Is that deliberate?

Comment: Oh, I pasted wrong code, of course I used CornerRadius, but with no effect :)

Comment: Please post the **real** code then. Otherwise, this question is completely useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```xml
<Border BorderBrush-"White"
        BorderThickness="1"
        CornerRadius="5"
        ... >
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="image.png" .../>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

Comment: My image is a "card" and needs to be flipped when viewing the "back". I used <Border.Projection> <PlaneProjection RotationY="180" /> </Border.Projection> to get that. HTH someone.